# Sass - Combine string with variable in a @for loop

Tags: css, sass

So, I'm trying to learn SCSS and thought I'd try using a simple for loop to set transition-delays on a series of `<li>` elements.

I managed to get it to work, but I'm having a hard time combining the two strings I want. For example, this works fine:

```
li {
       @for $i from 1 through 8 
       {
           &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) 
           {
           transition-delay: #{$i}s;
           }
       }                            
  }
```

But, this gives me a transition delay of whole seconds. I want it to be (zero point seconds). Like `0.#{$i}s;`

What am I missing? I've tried countless of variations and surely I'm just missing something really basic here? If I combine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check my example or [SassMeister Gist](http://sassmeister.com/gist/1e2428d8e938eecba016):

```
li {
  @for $i from 1 through 8 {
    &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
      transition-delay:  0.1s * $i;
    }
  }                            
}
```

Here's more on that matter: [All You Ever Need to Know About Sass Interpolation](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/all-you-ever-need-to-know-about-sass-interpolation--cms-21375)

Comment: Ah I see. I knew there was a way, should have thought of that myself though :p Thanx!

Comment: No, do not do this.  This is completely the wrong way to do it.

Comment: @cimmanon Thanks for pointing out, I have updated the answer.